# How to group radio buttons present in different panels as a single group?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have to group `RadioButton`s present in **different** `Panel`s as a **single group**. Sa,y for example, I have a `RadioButton` named `radBtn1` on `panel1` and `radBtn2` and `radBtn2` on `panel2`. Now I want to *group* all these radio buttons as a *single group* so that *only one* `RadioButton` is checked at a time.

Comment: I would argue that this could be indicative of poor UI\UX design. However, there is no _automated_ mechanism for getting the radio buttons to interact with each other in this way.

Comment: You will likely have to write some code to manually uncheck the other radio buttons when the `CheckedChanged` event fires on each radio button

Answer (score 1):

We can try uncheck `RadioButton`s *manually*. Let's assign `RadioButtons_CheckedChanged` event handler for *all* `RadioButtons` of interest:

```
private void RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // If we have a RadioButton Checked 
  if (sender is RadioButton current && current.Checked) {
    // We should remove Check from the rest RadioButtons:
    var rest = new Control[] { panel1, panel2} 
      .SelectMany(ctrl => ctrl             // all radiobuttons on panel1, panel2
         .Controls
         .OfType<RadioButton>())
      .Where(button => button != current); // don't touch current it should stay checked

    foreach (var button in rest)
      button.Checked = false;
  }
}
```